# How to make subsections not appear in the text?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have the following preamble and I want the subsection not to be visible in the
text.  Instead of Chapter 1 "Blah Blah" I only want "Blah Blah to be visible. With this code I did it bu the subsections are still visible in the text. e.g. 2.5 "blah blah".  How can I also remove 2.5 ??

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\Huge}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=2pt, font=small, labelformat = empty]{caption}

\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\useshorthands{;}
\defineshorthand{;}{?}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
```

Comment: Put \renewcommand\thesubsection{} in your preamble.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `titlesec` for this. The easiest way to get all sectional units unnumbered is to set `secnumdepth` to `-2` (or to `-1` if parts should be numbered):

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Niiiice...!!!  It worked perfectly..!!  Thanks a lot..!! :-)

Comment: @Stefanos You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept answers that best solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: One more thing ...!!  With the same preamble, each section is defined to start at almost the 2/3 of the page, meaning there is a small space and then goes the "Section 1: blah blah". Can I start each section at the beginning of the page like the other pages?

Comment: @Stefanos As a general rule, one question per post. Please consider opening a new question with this new requirement.